# How to create database and user in H2 DB in IDEA via script file?

Tags: sql, h2

I don't understand how to create user and database via H2 embedded DB in Intelij Idea

Can u write example of creation Database and User please with h2 syntax?

When I am trying to run this script :

```
CREATE USER GUEST PASSWORD 'abc';
```

in this file `createDatabaseAndUser.sql`

in this program :

```
  Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        //STEP 2: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //STEP 3: Execute a query
        ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conn);
        //Creating a reader object
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\PROJECTS\\src\\main\\resources\\createDatabaseAndUser.sql"));
        //Running the script
        sr.runScript(reader);
```

I gained an error :
`Error executing: CREATE USER GUEST PASSWORD 'abc'
.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE[*] USER GUEST PASSWORD 'abc'
"; SQL statement:
CREATE USER GUEST PASSWORD 'abc'
 [42000-199]`

Comment: What happened when you tried [create user](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_user)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But I need to create database too in this script

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE USER GUEST PASSWORD 'abc';` is really `Syntax error in SQL statement`. Because you write command in h2 syntax, but you have `.sql` extension in your migration file.

I don't exactly know how to solve this problem with H2 syntax. But you can solve it just by making your migration with SQL command.

Try to write this in your `createDatabaseAndUser.sql` file:

```
CREATE USER Guest WITH PASSWORD = 'abc';
```